# Error: MS Access file error, After deploy MS Office patch in December 2021

Tags: ms-access

When I open am MS Access file shared in a network drive, appears the error:  Could not lock file.
Some MS Office patches was deploy at December 2021

Answer (score 1):

The KB5002099 patch deployed in Client computers in December 2021, introduce a bug as a side effect of a security fix.

Here in the link  is the description of this patch -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-office-2016-december-14-2021-kb5002099-10670400-427f-4819-8de6-abd11e73100b

Inside this description, you will find the Know issue of this update, and the solution (KB4484211) How to get and install the update
Databases on network share can't be accessed by multiple users in Office 2016 (KB4484211) (microsoft.com)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/databases-on-network-share-can-t-be-accessed-by-multiple-users-in-office-2016-kb4484211-88a51f7f-f7dd-2d9c-0b96-b7fca0867a4f

Select download update for 32-bit version or 64-bits of Office 2016, This update is available only for manual download and installation from the Microsoft Download Center.